# Assignment of const to non-const in C

Tags: c, constants, void-pointers

In the following:

```
struct adt { void * A; };

int new_adt(const void * const A)
{
    struct adt * r = malloc(sizeof(struct adt));
    r->A = A;
}
```

I get:

> warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type

---

I know I can use

```
memcpy(&(r->A), &A, sizeof(void *));
```

to workaround it, but I must ask: Is there any alternative?

By using `const void * const` I pretend to say that no changes will be made to the input. Also, now that I think of it, `const void *` would suffice, wouldn't it? (Since I can't change the pointer so that it affects the caller)

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: Where did you declare `r`?  What is its type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you never want to modify `A` through its pointer from `adt`, then you should make *that* pointer const as well, i.e.:

```
struct adt {
    const void * A;
};
```

That will make the error go away.

If you *do* want to modify `A` through `adt`, then `new_adt` should take a non-const pointer.

---

Edit: A more general note, which may help:

The `const` keyword, in general, applies to the type immediately to its *left*. However, if there is no type to its left, it will apply to the type to the right.  So:
`const int * A` is the same as `int const * A` (the `const` applies to the `int`, not to the pointer), but in `int * const A`, the const applies to the pointer, not to the int.

There is a more comprehensive explanation on Wikipedia: [const-correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness). The 'Pointers and References' section of that page includes an example which covers the various combinations of const and non-const that you can apply to a pointer.

Comment: Thanks, but to be sure I understood: I want to replace the value of `A` in the future, as in `void replace(const void * const A, struct adt * r) {r->A = A;}`. Is this modifying the value of `A` through `adt`?

Comment: `const void * A` (or, equivalently, `void const * A`) means that you can change `A` to point somewhere else, but you can't change the contents of the thing `A` points to. So you'll still be able to do `r->A = new_A` without any problem.

Answer (score 7):

> By using const void * const I pretend to say that no changes will be made to the input.

You *have not* ***pretended*** to say that no changes will be made to the input, you have explicitly told the compiler that you have ***guaranteed*** that no changes will be made to the input.

You **MUST NOT** do what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

You can cast the const away:

```
r->A = (void *) A;
```

The issue, though, is less about how to avoid the warning and more about what you're trying to do. The compiler is warning you because you're telling the compiler that "A" is not writable, but you're trying to store it in a location that defines it as writable. That's generally not OK, semantically.

Imagine that "A" points to a location in your binaries data section; trying to write to it, after casting the const away, will most probably cause a segfault.

So, really, think about what you're trying to do more closely before trying to work around the compiler warning. They're warnings for a good reason.